# Given a measure on a measurable set, how do I compute the Lebesgue integral of a given function?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to study Measure Theory on my own. I think I understood the theoretical framework of how measure theory should work, but I'm having troubles because of the lack of practical examples and right now I have the following doubt: if I'm given the measure and a function, how do I explicitly compute the integral?

Here's a simple example of what I mean.

Let's say I have $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and my measure $\delta_1$ such that:

$$
      \delta_1(A) = 
      \begin{cases}
      1 & \text{if } 1 \in A \\
      0 & \text{if } 1 \notin A
    \end{cases}
$$

Let's say I take the function $f(x) = |x|$.
How do I compute the integral 
$$
\int_A f \, d\delta_1
$$

I do realise this is a very simple example, but what I don't understand is how, formally, my measure is supposed to act inside my integral.

Could you show me how to continue explicitly the equation?

$$\int_Af \, d\delta_1 = \cdots $$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is a little confusing because $A$ is sometimes an arbitrary set and sometimes the specific set $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered the concept for a general measure here: [How to calculate an integral given a measure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3250801/how-to-calculate-an-integral-given-a-measure/3250827#3250827)

I'll copy it below, then supplement with an example using the Dirac measure, like you are.

Recall the definition of the Lebesgue integral of $f$ on a measure space $(X,\mathfrak{F},\mu)$: If $f$ is non-negative, then

$$\int\limits_X f \, d\mu=\sup\left\lbrace\int\limits_X s\,d\mu:\ 0\leq s\leq f,\ s\text{ simple}\right\rbrace.$$ We define it on absolutely integrable functions which can be both positive and negative by breaking them into positive and negative parts $f^+=\max \{f,0\}$ and $f^-=-\min\{f,0\}$ (respectively), then applying the above to each piece. Also, if $f\in L^1$, there exists a sequence of simple functions $(s_n)$ converging to $f$ pointwise so that $$\int\limits_X f\,d\mu=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int\limits_X s_n \, d\mu.$$ To find this approximating sequence, we find monotone non-decreasing approximating sequences for the positive and negative parts of $f$ (you can find this construction in any textbook). So, we really just need to remember how to integrate simple functions:

If $s(x)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n c_j\chi_{A_j}(x),$ where $A_j\in\mathfrak{F},$ then $$\int\limits_X s \, d\mu = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n c_j\mu(A_j).$$ Putting this all together allows us to calculate the integral of $f\in L^1(X)$.

**For the example**, consider the Dirac measure for $x\in X$: $$\delta_x(A)=\chi_A(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x\notin A,\\ 1 &x\in A. \end{cases}$$ We'll claim that $$\int f\, d\delta_x=f(x).$$ To see this, check on a simple function $f=\sum c_j\chi_{A_j}$ to get $$\int f\, d\delta_x=\sum c_j\delta_x(A_j)=\sum c_j\chi_{A_j}(x)=f(x).$$ In your particular example, you will need to insert a cut-off over the set $A$. So, it will depend on whether or not $1\in A$. Since $|x|$ is equal to $1$ for $x=1$, the answer will be $\chi_A(1)$.

(To be slicker in justifying the expression for integrating with respect to $\delta_x$: for a fixed $x$, the constant function $g$ defined by $g(y)=f(x)$ is equal to $f$ $\delta_x$-a.e., as the set $\{y: f(x)=g(y)\neq f(y)\}$ does not contain $x$.
Hence, their integrals are the same, and the integral of $g$ is just $\delta_x(\text{whole space}) f(x)=f(x).$)

Comment: I edited this answer to change a number of things like $\displaystyle \int f d\mu$ to $\displaystyle \int f\, d\mu.$ That small space separating $d\mu$ from what is next to it is standard usage.

Comment: Ok so basically what you are saying is that first I have to find a simple function $s_n$ such that it tends to $f$. Then I have to integrate $s_n$, and then find the limit of this integral which should depend on $n$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Sometimes, you don't need to find an approximation simple functions if you know more about the measure itself. For example, I didn't have to approximate $|x|$ to integrate it with respect to the Dirac measure, but integrating with respect to the Dirac measure is especially easy (which is most readily seen by computing the integral for an arbitrary simple function).

Comment: Okay perfect! Thanks a lot.
But tell me something (actually I wanted to ask another question about that, and I think I will. If you want, I'll link it here to you): in this way I can evaluate the Lebesgue integral from the definition, thus without the Reimann integral, am I right? I mean, if I got it right, I could also evaluate the integral by using the fact that the Lebesgue and Reimann integral often coincide. But here you proceeded from the definition. Is this correct?

Comment: In the case of a function being Riemann integrable, then it's Lebesgue integrable with respect to the Lebesgue measure, and the results coincide. So, this gives an alternative way of computing the result. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was asking. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wait I have one more question left: when you write $\sum c_j \chi_{A_j}(x) = ... $ I would say that since $x$ only $\in$ a certain $Ai$, then $\sum c_j \chi_{A_j}(x) = c_i$.
And thus the whole integral should be equal to $c_i$. 
Why isn't that the case?

Comment: Well, I didn’t assume they were disjoint (could’ve, of course). And, really, that’s the same thing. But the important fact I wanted was that for any simple function, the integral is just evaluation at $x$.

Comment: So, here's my new question: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3598768/given-a-measure-on-a-measurable-space-and-a-function-to-integrate-what-is-the-c